# Outdated browser version in Microsoft Teams Desktop App

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm using Microsoft Teams desktop app in Windows 10.
I created a new Channel with a Web site Tab.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to surf in the Tab because a message is pop up saying:

*"Outdated browser version"
"Please update your Chrome version to 86 or higher"*

I reviewed the logs and the user agent is pointing to an old Chrome version:
"userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Teams/1.4.00.4167 **Chrome/80.0.3987.165** Electron/8.5.1 Safari/537.36"

On the contrary, if I open Microsoft Team web version I'm able to display the Tab and surf on it without any problem since my web browser is higher than 86.

How can I upgrade this feature. I need Microsoft Teams to use a higher version of Chrome in order to support the web page in the Tab.

Here are my apps versions:

- Microsoft Teams: 1.4.00.4167
- Chrome: 88.0.4324.190

Comment: Hi @Ayane, We tried to reproduce the issue in both Web and Desktop, but were not able to reproduce the issue. Could you please share us your manifest and repro steps to move further.

Comment: Hi @Ayane, are you still facing the issue.